# approximate a nonparametric CDF in R

Tags: nonparametric, cumulative-distribution-function, approximation, splines, nonparametric-regression

I have two vectors of same length. The first vector is a collection of realization from an unknown random variable. The second vector is the distribution computed at each particular realization.

A numerical example is:

```
A <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)
B <- punif(A, min = min(A), max = max(A), lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
```

I would like to get the values of the CDF (e.g. B) for realizations of the random variable other than those in the first vector (e.g. for points not in A). I tried `ksmooth` and `approx`, and after plotting the second seems to work best. What other `R` commands would you suggest? Nonparametric Regressions from `np` package?

Comment: Framed as a request for R code this is likely off topic (though it's fine to ask if you focus on the statistical issues; there's usually no problem with encouraging answers than incorporate R where possible). However I am not sure I clearly understand what you're seeking. Are you after something like an empirical cdf? (see `?ecdf` in R)

Comment: @glen_b I believe he wants to plot the randomly generated values vs the CDF at each of those points, and then use an R function to fit a curve to that so he can get fitted CDF values for any point in the desired range. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the empirical CDF would give him a step function that wouldn't allow him to do this.

Comment: @Patty that's correct. Empirical CDF is a step function, which is the same thing as vector `B` above. I would like to smooth this function